Image not shrinkwrapping around my sphere object
Im trying to shrinkwrap an image onto a golf ball object, the front of the image shrinkwraps fine, but the corners are projecting out making a mess. I have subdivided my image 100 loops cuts, so it would be plenty to shrinkwrap onto the object.



Move the image even closer and curve it first. Use "nearest face" instead of "project".

When Shrinkwrap modifier is set to Project method, every point on the plane will try to collide with something along its normal direction, those points which collide with nothing will stay still.To solve it, we can try to change the method to Target Normal Project. But as the image plane is too long, the effect is still weird, so we need to bend the image plane into a more cylindrical shape before shrinkwrap.
Here are the overall settings:

Ctrl+A > Rotation, to make sure image plane has no rotating transform.
Give the plane a SimplyDeform modifier like in my screenshot. You can tweak the bend Angle to make the plane go around the ball more evenly.
Add a Shrinkwrap modifier and set the method to Target Normal Project.
Finally, you can tweak the plane's position along the facing axis to change the final shape.


